# TYPO3-Console with composer -> propagate changes to extensions

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I have installed TYPO3 (7.6 LTS) via composer plus TYPO3-Console (CLI installation) and want to utilize TYPO3-Console throughout the lifecycle.

Initially I have entered this in my composer.json:

```
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms": "~7.6",

    "typo3/cms-about": "*",
    "typo3/cms-aboutmodules": "*",
    "helhum/typo3-console": "^4.6",
    "typo3-ter/t3adminer": "7.0.8"
  }
```

now I finished installation and notice that I actually also needed "cms-recycler" for example. I add this to the composer.json file:

```
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms": "~7.6",

    "typo3/cms-about": "*",
    "typo3/cms-aboutmodules": "*",
    "typo3/cms-recycler": "*",
    "helhum/typo3-console": "^4.6",
    "typo3-ter/t3adminer": "7.0.8"
  }
```

and then I type `composer update`; if it were a remote TER extension, that would fetch me a remote extension. So far so good, but:

How do I tell TYPO3-console (vendor/bin/typo3cms) to parse the composer.json file and look if I added or removed any extensions? I didn't find a specific command for that; the `typo3cms install:generatepackagestates` command only seems to create the currently installed extensionlist, not the one contained in composer.json.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there simply no support for this yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `composer dumpautoload` to update the internal list of extensions to activate upon `install:generatepackagestates`.

Comment: Great. That did indeed work. Thanks a lot! I think it might have worked properly before already, but I didn't pay attention that my "composer update" was not properly executed.